# Converting binary to decimal within a case structure in LabVIEW 2018

Tags: boolean, logic, system, labview, circuit

I have two CONTROLs (buttons specifically) that when activated act as one bit each. 
So it basically means the highest number I can produce is 2 by having both buttons activated at the same time. EDIT: Okay what I meant to say was that the highest output I'm going to be able to produce is two because I only have 2 buttons, each representing a 1. So 1+1=2.

However, this is only understood logically because the bits are yet to be converted to a numerical(decimal) format. I can use a 'Boolean to 0,1' converted directly to get the values but I'm instructed to use a case structure to complete this.

Right now I'm completely perplexed because a case structure needs exactly ONE case selector but I have TWO buttons. Secondly, this problem seems way too SIMPLE to require a case structure therefore making it genuinely harder to use a more complex method.

Comment: Use one case structure inside each case of another case structure?

Answer (score 1):

> So it basically means the highest number I can produce is 2 by having both buttons activated at the same time.

A 2bit-number can have four values, 0...3, hmm?

In general, if the two booleans are bits of the number, or the number can somehow be calculated from the bools, do it.

But if the number can have predefined values which depend on the booleans, but can not be calculated from them, you need some other kind of case distinction. Maybe, whoever instructed you, had this in mind.

1. You can make a case structure for the first boolean, and in each case, insert a second case structure for the second boolean. This is good when there will be more complex code and logic depending on the boolenans, so you can easily concentrate on one combination of values. For simple cases, this lacks overview, and when adding a third boolean, it's lots of work.
2. Calculate an interim value, and connect it to a single case structure. Now, there is only one case structure, but you have no overview over all cases. Note I've changed the radix of the case struture to boolean, so you can see the bits in the selector.
3. Use a simple array to take a value from
4. Create a lookup table with predefined conditions and values

(Note that the first two solutions force you to implement each case, while the last two do not - what if your arrays are of size 3, only?)

[image]

Comment: I really love and appreciate how informative and articulate you are. Thank you so much, honestly. I'm extremely grateful.